# JMeter JMS Point-to-Point Request Response: "No reply message received"

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, jmeter

I have created a JMS Point-to-Point Request Response test as documented in the JMeter manual.

My JMeter Point-to-Point Configuration:

[image]

When I run it, however, it always times out on the response. If I look at the sampler log file, I seem `rm="No reply message received"`:

```
<sample t="1016" lt="0" ts="1350683197138" s="false" lb="JMS Point-to-Point" rc="" rm="No reply message received" tn="Attributes Fetch 1-1" dt="text" by="0"/>
```

I know my consumer is set up correctly to reply based on replyTo JMS header. In fact - if I look at the ActiveMQ management console, it shows me that the reply queue I specified has queued and dequeued exactly the number of messages in the test. So it looks like JMeter *is* dequeing them, but something goes awry after that!

My ActiveMQ Management Console:

[image]

Has anyone been able to do this successfully with JMeter and ActiveMQ?
I am using JMeter 2.8 and ActiveMQ 5.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly due to correlation attributes chosen.

Read carefully this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Point-to-Point

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the extra documentation!  I was able to resolve it by removing my entry for the response queue and de-selecting the checkbox for the alernate correlation ID.  Removing the response queue makes jmeter use a temp queue, and that seems to have resolved it (if I add the response queue value back, it fails again).  I guess the Point-to-Point tutorial in the user guide isn't exactly right!