# JMeter JMS Testing processing time

Tags: jmeter, activemq-classic

I would like to measure the time with JMeter test scenario from enqueuing a message into an ActiveMQ Queue and until it ends up in a different Queue. In between I have Apache Camel logic which does message transformation and enrichments. 
I tried Jmeter Point-to-Point Sampler, where I filled my input and output queues in the "JNDI Name Request Queue" and "JNDI Name Response Queue" text fields. Also used JMS Message ID as Correlation ID. Camel receives the message, processes it and submits it to the output queue. But JMeter doesn't consumes it. I see following error message: 
Response message: No reply message received

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Yusuf

Comment: possible duplicate of [JMeter JMS Point-to-Point Request Response: "No reply message received"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982998/jmeter-jms-point-to-point-request-response-no-reply-message-received)

Comment: I read this and tried to set Correlation Id by Request Message Id and Response Message Id. But no matter what I did, JMeter could not relate  the incoming message to the outgoing message. What I recognized is that the message id was changing while flowing throw the broker (have multiple JMS bridges in place). Could that be the reason?